# How to validate 2 digit month and 4 digit year is valid?

Tags: php, regex

I'm taking a 2 digit month and a 4 digit year from a form field. How can I validate the month and year are valid?

I'm using PHP's preg_match and so far I have the following for the month field: `^[0-1][0-9]` which so far tests the first digit should either be a 0 or a 1. However, I need to make sure no one selects anything higher than 2 for the second digit if the first digit is 1.

For the year, I'm using `^(20)\d{2}$` which validates if the year is 20xx, but does not exclude years in the past. I only want to validate current and future years.

Comment: don't you also want to validate that the month is current or future?

Comment: To mention, there are tools that generate regex ranges, [like this one](https://3widgets.com/). Regex for eg for 2021-2099 could look like [`^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:202[1-9]|20[3-9][0-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/yFqYSg/1) and each year you will have to adjust your pattern for not matching in the past ... :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)?

```
$dateInput = '06/2022';

list($monthStr, $yearStr) = explode('/', $dateInput);


$month = filter_var((int)$monthStr, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
                    ['options' => ['min_range' => 1, 
                                   'max_range' => 12]]);

$year = filter_var((int)$yearStr, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
                   ['options' => ['min_range' => 2021, 
                                  'max_range' => 2099]]);
                                  
echo "month=$month\nyear=$year";
```

I need to cast the strings to integers first because `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` doesn't work with leading zero's, and only `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` will work with the range options. `$month` will either contain `false` or a valid month number and `$year` will either contain `false` or a valid year.

Comment: I keep failing month validation. Is it because html form input passes it as a string instead of an integer?

Comment: No, that cannot be the reason? What are you using as the `$dateInput` string?

Comment: Anyway, `filter_var()` is a modern solution for filtering input from users. I didn't expect to need to `explode()` the input first, but added that afterwards.

Comment: That worked! Definitely much easier than what I was attempting.

Comment: @germanshedder I made a bit of a mess of it. This is the final version, that does actually work: [PHP Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f6d716226e418d520c5c0d8455bcb501dc7e081)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you have two separate regexes:

- `^[0-1][0-9]` - month
- `^(20)\d{2}$` - year

then may I presume these are separate input fields?

Regex is bad at arithmetic, period. "I only want to validate current and future years." is a fool's errand for regex.

Why not:

```
if(
    $year >= date( 'Y' ) &&
    $month >= 1 && $month <= 12
)
{
    // Valid
}
```

Comment: It is a single input field. I'm using PHP explode on the '/' character.

Comment: @germanshedder Okay, so declare `$month = $explode[0]; $year = $explode[1];` right before the `if(){}`

Comment: OP: That's fine. It should still work. You can also use `list($month, $year) = explode('/',$input);`